# ServiceStack Redis caching not serializing as expected

Tags: caching, redis, servicestack

We have a class in our project that contains cache information:

```
public class SOLECache
{
    public DateTime CreatedDTM { get; set; }
    public int UserID { get; set; }
    public int MaxAgeSeconds { get; set; }
    public object Data { get; set; }
}
```

where property Data hold the object that we want to caching which could be of any type. Because we have a production environment with multiple web servers we are trying to use Redis and ServiceStack to handle caching. Now the cache is properly stored on Redis server and that part is working fine. The problem is that when we try to get the cache:

```
 _cacheClient.Get<AppUser>("someCacheKey");
```

we always get a NULL value for our Data property. So basically it is clear that the data is stored on Redis server under the proper key but when we retrieve it we get everything but the Data property which is always NULL.

Can anyone give me any insights into why is this the case? Could it be because the object we are storing in the data property has some read only properties and a few methods - it's not a clean POCO? Here is a sample structure of the object being stored:

```
public class AppUser
{ 
   public int UserId {get; set;}
   public string FirstName {get; set;}
   public string LastName {get; set;}
   public string FullName
   {
      get {
         return FirstName + " " + LastName;
      }
   }
   public void DoSomething()
   {
      // some method logic here...
   }
}
```

Could this class be causing the ServiceStack.RedisClient to not serialize AppUser instance properly?

The way we set the cache in Redis is:

```
_cacheClient.Set("someCacheKey", soleCache, DateTime.UtcNow.AddSeconds(soleCache.MaxAgeSeconds))
```

where soleCache is an instance of SOLECache with populated Data property. The data stored on Redis is the following:

```
{"CreatedDTM":"2013-06-28T13:45:56.5091664-04:00","UserID":123,"MaxAgeSeconds":60,"Data":{"FullName":"John M Doe","FirstName":"John","MiddleName":"M","LastName":"Doe","Email":"me@here.com","BackupEmail":"me@there.com","GradYear":null,"PostalCode":"12345     ","Location":"12345     ","City":null,"IsValid":true,"Active":true,"AccessLevel":10,"CurrentApp":0,"CurrentURL":"http://localhost:4387/","RequestMethod":"GET","IsMobile":false,"IsInApp":false,"ServerName":"ITSWEB-JMDOE","ID":40117,"IsAdmin":true,"Theme":"basic","ExpirationDT":null,"WebFolderName":"jmdoe","ProgramCD":null,"BranchCD":"MBIM","RoleOverride":0,>"CurrentAppRoleID":0,"EnableNativeMailFLG":false,"PasswordStatus":"GOOD","CampusCD":"M","Campus":"Smallville","DisclaimerDate":"2012-07-02T10:55:54.297","SecurityQuestion":null,"ClassificationMSK":4,"IsLinkedToCurrentApp":false,"IsBlockedFromCurrentApp":false,"IsBlockedMessageText":null,"CurrentAppRoleName":null,"AssignedAppRoleID":0,"AppSmallGroup":0,"PermissionsArray":[],"AdminPermissionsArray":[],"ViewLevel":[],"LastLoginDTM":"2013-06-27T16:28:23.21","Session":{"SessionID":"1923dac2-f3af-4dc5-ad51-7202fc077ba3","SessionCreatedDTM":"2013-06-28T09:03:13.12","SessionTimeout":60,"SessionUserID":40117,"SessionCurrentApp":0,"SessionLastViewDTM":"2013-06-28T13:24:37.69","SessionUserAgent":"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/28.0.1500.52 Safari/537.36","SessionIP":"127.0.0.1","SessionLastURL":"http://localhost:4387/Home/CacheInfo","SessionServer":"ITSWEB-JMDOE","LastLoginDTM":null,"SessionLoginMethod":null,"ADUserName":null,"ADPassword":null,"Errors":{},"HasErrors":false,"ModelState":{}},"CurrentInstanceID":0,"CurrentPageHasNotes":false,"CurrentPageIsFavorited":false,"BrowserBrand":"Chrome","BrowserVersion":"28.0","BrowserPlatform":"Windows 8","BrowserValid":true,"Favorites":[],"FullNameWithEmail":"John M Doe (jmdoe@here.com)","FullNameWithoutMiddleName":"John Doe","IsStudent":true,"Errors":{},"HasErrors":false,"ModelState":{}}}
```

We have traced the issue to ServiceStack.Text.JsonSerializer method which for some reason does not serialize this object properly. When we replace this method with NewtonSoft's Json Serializer it works fine... Seems to be the issue with ServiceStack but I might be wrong...

Comment: Not quite following this question...How are you inserting into the cache? _cacheClient.Set<SOLEcache>("someCacheKey", AppUserObject). What does the string in Redis look like?

Comment: @paaschpa Please take a look at the additional information I provided in the question.

Answer (score 1):

**we always get a NULL value for our Data property.**
So, it looks like you are inserting into the cache an object of type `SOLECache` (from question:*where soleCache is an instance of SOLECache with populated Data property.*)
And, you want to pull data out from the cache into type `AppUser` (from question: *`_cacheClient.Get<AppUser>("someCacheKey");`*)
Maybe this is just a typo (I don't see a Data property on `AppUser`) but switching types could be the issue.

You should be able to insert into the cache type `SOLECache` and get type `SOLECache` out. As long as you have `JsConfig.ExcludeTypeInfo = false;` (which is the default) it should populate the Data property with the correct type. It looks like you may have `JsConfig.ExcludeTypeInfo = true;` because I don't see a `__type` field in the data stored in Redis (this is how ServiceStack.Text knows what type object Data is). If you are excluding TypeInfo, deserializing the cache data should fill the Data property with the JSON string.